# How to correct error with VBA goalseek in loop code

Tags: excel, vba

I am a newb at VBA and would greatly appreciate your help on the following. I have an Excel model where I would set cell D3 to an IRR of 5% by changing cell G40, which is the price used to calculate revenue. At the same time, I have range E154:E160 with upfront cost. I would like to know what price is needed at each upfront cost to get to the 5% IRR, so iterating through rows 154-160.

The error message I am getting is Run-time error '1004': Method 'Range' of object'_Global' failed. I think where the debug is hung up is how I handled the goalseek ranges.

Thank you!

```
Sub goalseek()

Dim i As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Set sht = wb.Sheets("monthly")

Dim lastrow As Long
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
For i = 154 To lastrow
    Range("d3" & i).goalseek goal:=Range(0.05), changingcell:=Range("g40" & i)
Next i
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: the error is you can't add i to your Range like you do.  You need to use offset `sht.Range("D3").Offset(i,0).goalseek ect ....`

Comment: ^^^ likewise `changingcell:=Range("g40" & i)`.  And `goal:=Range(0.05)` is invalid.  Should be `goal:=0.05` or refer to a cell containing 0.05.  And qualify all ranges with `sht`

Comment: Thanks sorceri  & chris neilsen. I was getting a reference isn't valid error after those changes. I got the code below to work, based on Ed Bodmer's code.  Sub goalseek()

Range("d3").goalseek goal:=0.05, changingcell:=Range("g40")

End Sub

Sub oneway()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

For Row = 154 To 174

Range("g40") = Cells(Row, 5)

goalseek

Cells(Row, 6) = Range("g40")

Next Row

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub